Multiple recurrence property is preserved under invertible extensions
The Multiple Recurrence (MR) Theorem states that for a measure-preserving system $(X, \mathcal{B}, \mu, T)$, and a set $A \in \mathcal{B}$, with $\mu(A) > 0$, and for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$, we have that
$$\liminf_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N \mu( A \cap T^{-n}A \cap T^{-2n}A \cap \dots T^{-kn} A) > 0.$$
I am trying to understand its proof from Einsiedler & Ward's Ergodic Theory book. They first reduce the proof to invertible extensions, by showing that any measure-preserving system has an invertible extension and that the MR property is preserved under such invertible extensions. However, they leave the latter as an exercise, and I have not been able to prove it.


I am proving that MR (or SZ) property for the invertible extension implies the same property for $(X,\mu,T)$. Of course, the other direction has the same proof with the roles of the systems interchanged.
Let $\tilde{A}=\{x\in \tilde{X}: x(0)\in A\}$ be as above. Then $\tilde{\mu}(\tilde{A})=\mu(A)>0$ and $(\tilde{X},\tilde{\mu},\tilde{T})$ is the invertible extension, so by assumption you know that
$$\liminf_{N\to \infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N \tilde{\mu}(\tilde{A} \cap \tilde{T}^{-n}\tilde{A} \cap \cdots \cap \tilde{T}^{-kn}\tilde{A})>0. $$
To conclude just observe that
$$\tilde{\mu}(\tilde{A} \cap \tilde{T}^{-n}\tilde{A} \cap \cdots \cap \tilde{T}^{-kn}\tilde{A})=\mu(A \cap T^{-n}A \cap \cdots \cap T^{-kn}A).$$
This follows from the fact that $\pi: \tilde{X} \to X$ defined by $\pi(x)=x(0)$ is a factor map from $(\tilde{X},\tilde{\mu},\tilde{T})$ to $(X,\mu,T)$, which$-$among other things$-$means that $$\mu=\tilde{\mu} \circ \pi^{-1}$$ and the fact that
$$\pi^{-1}(A \cap T^{-n}A \cap \cdots \cap T^{-kn}A)=\tilde{A} \cap \tilde{T}^{-n}\tilde{A} \cap \cdots \cap \tilde{T}^{-kn}\tilde{A}.$$
To see the latter equality observe that
$$x \in \pi^{-1}(A \cap T^{-n}A \cap \cdots \cap T^{-kn}A) \iff T^{in}x(0) \in A,\ \text{for}\ i=0,1,\ldots,k $$
and by definition this is equivalent to
$$x(in) \in A,\ \text{for}\ i=0,1,\ldots,k \iff \tilde{T}^{in}x \in \tilde{A},\ \text{for}\ i=0,1,\ldots,k.$$

I had a follow up question regarding the next result in the book: why is invertiblity of $\tilde{T}$ required when defining the Borel probability space factor: fix $A \in \tilde{\mathcal{B}}$ of positive measure and define $\phi: \tilde{X} \to {0,1}^\mathbb{Z},\ \phi(x) = \chi_A (\tilde{T}^n x)$. My guess is, since we require $\tilde{T}^n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. But why can't we just take ${0,1}^\mathbb{N}$ instead.

Invertibility is not necessary in this part of the proof. Indeed, if you can prove the result for Borel probability spaces and non-invertible m.p. transformations, then you have it via extensions in the general case. However, it is used in a few cases below. For example, first they prove the result for Kronecker systems, but these are invertible.  See also Proposition 7.15.
